# Jquery hover_caption plugin hiding transparency, Is it the z-index

Tags: jquery, css, hover, z-index

I am trying to hover overlay black text on white transparencies over imgs in a ul, but I think the transparency is hiding behind the img. I'm using Corey Schires' hover_caption jquery plugin.
Here is a link to my code.

http://blooming-citadel-2598.herokuapp.com/Residential/

and the jquery library
https://github.com/coryschires/hover-caption

```
(function($) {
$.hover_caption = {
  defaults: {
    caption_font_size: '13px',
    caption_color: 'black',
    caption_bold: false,
    caption_default: "fix me"
   }
}

$.fn.extend({
    hover_caption: function(config) {

  var config = $.extend({}, $.hover_caption.defaults, config);

    return this.each(function() {

      var image = $(this);

      // set variable for wrapper div
      var width = image.width();
      var height = image.height();

      // variables for caption
      var caption_padding = width * .07; // dynamic margin depending on img width

      //  set caption to title attr if set
      var caption = image.attr('title') ? image.attr('title') : config.caption_default;

      // add necessary html and css
      image
        .css({
          'z-index': '0',
          'position': 'relative'
        })
       .wrap('<div>')
       .parent()
        .css({
          'width': width,
          'height': height
        })
        .prepend('<h3>'+ caption +'</h3>')
        .find('h3')
        .addClass('hover_caption_caption') // use this hook for additional styling
        .css({
          'padding': caption_padding,
          'color': config.caption_color,
          'width': width,
          'font-size': config.caption_font_size,
          'position': 'absolute',
          'margin': 0
        })
        .hide();

        if (config.caption_bold) { image.css('font-weight', 'bold') };

        // add hover event to toggle message
        image.parent().hover(function() {
          $(this).addClass('hover_caption').find('h3').show();
        }, function() {
          $(this).removeClass('hover_caption').find('h3').hide();
        });

      })
    }
})

})(jQuery);
```

He sets the z-index of the img to -1 in his jquery, I had to change this to 0 so that the images wouldn't hide under their parents. This also broke everything.  The images are nested in the parent hover element div.hover_caption

```
div.hover_caption {
    background-image: url(/img/hover_image_white.gif);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255, 0.8);
    z-index: 1000!important;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your img tag inside your div is logically being put on top of your div's background. You can't change that behaviour with z-index. What you could do for example is add `opacity: 0.4` to `div.hover_caption img`. That'll make your image transparent so that the background on your div shows through it.

Comment: Thanks! Works beautifully.